Integral of two-variable function over level sets
Suppose I wish to compute the following integral:
$$
\int_{D}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,f(x,y)
$$
where the domain of integration $D$ is given by
$$
D=\left\{(x,y):0\leq g(x,y)\leq 1\right\}
$$
Suppose further that the integrand $f(x,y)$ depends only on $(x,y)$ through the same function $g(x,y)$ that appears in $D$; that is
$$
f(x,y)=f(g(x,y))
$$
Is it possible, for a well-behaved function $g(x,y)$, to change integration variables from $(x,y)$ to $(s,t)$, where $g(x,y)=s$ are the level sets of $g(x,y)$ and $t$ is (presumably) normal to the level sets, without knowing a convenient parametrization for the level sets of $g(x,y)$?
For example, if $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$, I know that the level sets of $g(x,y)$ are concentric circles, which are conveniently described by the polar coordinates $x=r\cos{\phi},\: y=r\sin{\phi}$. The integral then becomes, in terms of $(r,\phi)$
$$
\int_D\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,f(x,y)
\rightarrow
\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi\int_0^1 r^3\mathrm{d}r
=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
but for a more complicated $g(x,y)$, such a parameterization of the level will not be so obvious.
